# CSS - I want to handle the background colour of table cells

Tags: css

[image]

The above picture is a table with data and i want to handle the background colour of each table cell. 
I want to leave two table rows and change the background colour of the next cell.

How to handle this with CSS

Comment: Is this what you want? `tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}`

Comment: Have you read [the documentation on `:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)? You should be able to come up with a simple solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
table tr {
  background: #FFF;
}
table tr:nth-child(4n), table tr:nth-child(4n-1) {
  background: #999;
}
```